# removeAtIndex() not working on Swift array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a Swift n00b question.
I'm having a hard time understanding why I cannot remove an element from an array.

I first filter it twice to contain only the values I need:

```
let filteredShowtimes = movieShowtimes.filter{$0.dateTime.laterDate(newStartTime!).isEqualToDate($0.dateTime)}
var furtherFilteredShowtimes = filteredShowtimes.filter{$0.endTime.earlierDate(endTime!).isEqualToDate($0.endTime)}
```

And, down the line, inside a while loop that depends on the size of the array - but doesn't iterate over it or modify it - I try removing the first element like so:

```
furtherFilteredShowtimes.removeAtIndex(0)
```

But the element count remains the same.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Here's the whole code:

```
while(furtherFilteredShowtimes.count > 0) {
   println("showtime \(furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.dateTime)")
      //if the start time of the movie is after the start of the time period, and its end before
      //the requested end time
      if (newStartTime!.compare(furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.dateTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) && (endTime!.compare(furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.endTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) {
          let interval = 1200 as NSTimeInterval
          //if the matching screenings dict already contains one movie,
          //make sure the next one starts within 20 min of the previous
          //one
          if(theaterMovies.count > 1 && endTime!.timeIntervalSinceDate(newStartTime!) < interval {
              //add movie to the matching screenings dictionary
              println("we have a match with \(movies[currentMovie.row].title)")
              theaterMovies[furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.dateTime] = movies[currentMovie.row].title
              //set the new start time for after the added movie ends
              newStartTime = movieShowtimes.first!.endTime
              //stop looking for screenings for this movie
              break
          }
          else if(theaterMovies.count == 0) {
             //add movie to the matching screenings dictionary
             theaterMovies[furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.dateTime] = movies[currentMovie.row].title
             println("we have a new itinerary with \(movies[currentMovie.row].title)")
             //set the new start time for after the added movie ends
             newStartTime = furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.endTime
             //stop looking for screenings for this movie
             break
         }
     }
     else { //if the showtime doesn't fit, remove it from the list
         println("removing showtime \(furtherFilteredShowtimes.first!.dateTime)")
         furtherFilteredShowtimes.removeAtIndex(0)
     }
```

---

}

Comment: Can you show the code for your while loop?

Comment: Yeah, there must be something wrong with your loop if it's not iterating...

Answer (score 0):

You only say `removeAtIndex(0)` in one place, in an `else`.

So if it doesn't happen, that means that line is never being executed because the `else` is not executed - the `if` is executed instead.

And you `break` at the end of each `if`, so that's the end of the `while` loop!

In other words, let's pretend that the first two nested `if` conditions succeed. Your structure is like this:

```
while(furtherFilteredShowtimes.count > 0) {
    if (something) {
        if (somethingelse) {
            break
```

`break` means jump out of the `while`, so if those two `if` conditions succeed, that's the end! We never loop. We certainly will never get to the `removeAtIndex()`.

Comment: Yep. That's exactly how I structured it. I was items to be removed only when the conditions aren't meant and the while loop continues. I can see in my console printouts that when that else clause is reached, the remove is not performed.

Comment: Can you add to your code the code that prints that info in the console? I suspect there is something funny about how you are determining this.